# Some fonts in Inkscape don't display in Inkscape

Tags: fonts, inkscape, css

I've noticed that some fonts don't display properly in Inkscape (0.92.3). Take Lato for example ([downloaded from](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/download/lato) fontsquirrel). It contains 9 different weights (excluding Italics). Some display fine, some don't.

I've noticed that the ones that don't in the Text and Font selector box have a CSS style of " weight=XXX". If they have italics in the name, the italics works, but not the weight.

[image: weight= styles]

I've done some research and it seems related to bug [167353](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/167353), but that's fixed, at least for those without the " weight=".

I opened the font in fontforge to see if I could find where the weight= is coming from, but there is nothing under the font info.

Questions:

1) Is this a new bug in Inkscape, or in the font?

2) Is there a way to edit the font to change the " weight=XXX" to something else? Maybe that is the problem???

Comment: There is [an old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1555109) which hasn't been fixed yet.  However I downloaded Lato from Google fonts, and it only seems to be two of the fonts which are affected (weight=251 hairline, and hairline italic) - all the others are working for me.

Comment: Tbh. I think this question belongs into the Inkscape bug tracker, not on stackexchange. Would you be able to make a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

1) Based on Billy Kerr's comment, and the link, this is a bug in Inkscape IMHO.

2) The CSS name seems to be coming from the OS/2 tab. If you edit the font (I used fontforge), and change the following, the name goes away. Under *Element -> Font Info*, in OS/2, there is a drop down for weight class. The name Inkscape gives is slightly different, but I believe this is the source of the CSS name. It's likely recorded as a number, and Inkscape assigns it's own name.

I've partially fixed the problem by:

- Change the weight under OS/2 to an even multiple of 100, whatever is closest.
- Under PS Names, change the Fontname, Family Name, and Name for Humans to something else. I really just added a prefix after Lato. Remember that Fontname can't have spaces.
- Under TTF names, I changed the Preferred Family to the same thing.

Generated the font, deleted old font, and installed new font. Restarted Inkscape and it seems to work.

Update: You don't really need to delete the old font. It works fine for other programs. But you will have two of the same if you don't.